Concatenate two dataframes with different headers
How can I concatenate 2 dataframes with headers of different length? I want to add the headers of the second dataframe as a row.
Below is my df1:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 3], 'C': [3, 4]})

df1

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4

df2:
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': [34, 'e'], 'E': ['rt', 'rt']})

df2

    D   E
0  34  rt
1   e  rt

My expected output:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2,'D',34,'e'], 'B': [2, 3,'E','rt','rt'], 
                   'C': [3, 4,'','','']})

df

    A   B  C
0   1   2  3
1   2   3  4
2   D   E   
3  34  rt   
4   e  rt   

My attempts thus far failed to achieve my expected output:
(1)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0/1)

(2)
df1_header = pd.DataFrame([df2.columns], columns=df1.columns)
df2.columns = df1.columns 
result = pd.concat([df1_header, df1, df2], ignore_index=True)


be aware that you can't notify people that are not yet involved in your question. I just happened to see your question by chance ;)

Here's one approach:
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            df1,
            df2.T.reset_index().T.rename(
                columns={k: v for k, v in iter(enumerate(df1.columns))}
                )
        ],
        axis=0,
        ignore_index=True
    )
)

Output
    A   B  C
0   1   2  3
1   2   3  4
2   D   E   
3  34  rt   
4   e  rt   

Explanation

Move column names for df2 to the first row with df.T, df.reset_index and again df.T. With the reset, df2 will now have column names [0, 1] instead of ['D', 'E'].
Next, we can use a dict comprehension to map the column names from df1 and pass an iterator (iter) to df.rename with the enumerated version of df1.columns.
Finally, use pd.concat on axis=0 and ignore the index.
Your output has empty strings instead of NaN values. If you'd like to insist on that, add df.fillna('').


it is correct. can you suggest one changes. what if i want below output.
D   E    2

0  34  rt  NaN
1   e  rt  NaN
2   A   B    C
3   1   2    3
4   2   3    4
I just want second df on top and first df below it?

Could you please add this output as an edit to your question. Here, in the form of a comment, it's not clear what you mean.

Thanks i just did small change in your code:
df = (     pd.concat(         [             df2,             df1.T.reset_index().T.rename(columns=dict(enumerate(df2.columns)))         ],         axis=0,         ignore_index=True     ) )

I see, you want to change the order of df1 and df2 basically. Yes, your adjustment for that will be correct :)

I would avoid transposing since if can mess up the dtypes.
A simple approach would be to create a DataFrame from the intermediate header and use it in the concat:
cols = df1.columns[:df2.shape[1]] # ['A', 'B']

out = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([df2.columns], columns=cols),
                 df2.set_axis(cols, axis=1)], ignore_index=True
               ).fillna('') # optional

If df2 can be wider than df1:
cols = (df1.columns[:df2.shape[1]].tolist()
       +df2.columns[df1.shape[1]:].tolist())

out = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([df2.columns], columns=cols),
                 df2.set_axis(cols, axis=1)], ignore_index=True
               ).fillna('') # optional

Output:
    A   B    C
0   1   2  3.0
1   2   3  4.0
2   D   E     
3  34  rt     
4   e  rt     

Intermediates:
# pd.DataFrame([df2.columns], columns=cols)
    A  B
 0  D  E

# df2.set_axis(cols, axis=1)
     A   B
 0  34  rt
 1   e  rt

